# How do you create references on firebase now that it has updated the sdk config

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new coding in Javascript I am implementing firebase realtime database. I need to create references. I have this code in my html and javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>I-Verbs</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <h1>Practica de Irregular Verbs</h1>
</header>
<div>
    <button>Boton</button>
    <form>
        <input id=infinitive type="text" name="infinitive">
        <input id=pasttense type="text" name="past tense">
        <input id=participle type="text" name="participle">
        <input id=meaning type="text" name="meaning">       
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="logica.js"></script>

</body>
</html
```

JavaScript:

```
 // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
 import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app.js";
  import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase- 
  analytics.js";
  import {datab } from 'firebase/database';


 // Your web app's Firebase configuration
 // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
 const firebaseConfig={ // copied from the database
 ...
 };

 // Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const data=datab(app) // not sure if it is right

// how to create the database and then the references????


//References

var r1=database.ref('Irregular Verbs/arise') /// hwo to create this 



//Actions, here I try to get teh references and write them into the forms
r1.once('value').then(function(snap){
alert(document.getElementById('infinitive').value=snap.val())   

 })
```

I used to create references with:

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var dbRef =firebase.database()
var c1Ref= dbRef.ref('Diseno/carrusel1')
```

But now I cannot figure out how to do it. Please help I am new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on [reading and writing with v9](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web-version-9):

```
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";

const database = getDatabase();
```

And on building a reference:

```
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue} from "firebase/database";

const db = getDatabase();
const starCountRef = ref(db, 'posts/' + postId + '/starCount');
```

And on reading once:

```
import { getDatabase, ref, child, get } from "firebase/database";

const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
get(child(dbRef, `users/${userId}`)).then((snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
  } else {
    console.log("No data available");
  }
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Based on that, yours should be something like:

```
import { getDatabase, ref, child, get } from "firebase/database";

const dbRef = ref(getDatabase(), "Irregular Verbs/arise");
get(dbRef).then((snap) => {
  alert(document.getElementById('infinitive').value=snap.val())   
})
```

Comment: Sure! did it jus last question I have an error in this part "firebase/database" is this necessary to write  "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase/database.js", or just "firebase/database"? thanks

Comment: In the `script` tag in the HTML you use the full URL, and then in the `import` statement in the JavaScript file you use the package name.

Comment: I add     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.8.1/firebase-app.js"></script><script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.8.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="logica.js"></script> and just this   import "firebase/app";
  import "firebase/analytics";
  import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/database" and it does not work

Comment: That's v8 that you're using there, so I recommend opening anew question for that with its own [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).